# Align two imageView with textView XML in android

Tags: android, xml, listview, imageview, alignment

I have a problem with my xml for android.
I have this layout to use it in each line of a Listview (that works fine).

I want to put two lines (head and body) of text, and align Right of the first line I have to put two ImageView. (Also have first of all a hidden textView)

Something like this:
[image]

My problem is when I try to put both imageViews (with only one it shows fine, but with two don't show nothing).

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TvIdGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImgNewConvGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/new_messages" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImgNewGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/new_group" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

sorry for my english and thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you set on using `LinearLayout`? If not, `RelativeLayout` should give you everything you are asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly then I believe this should be close to what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TvIdGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImgNewConvGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/new_messages" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImgNewGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImgNewConvGroup"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/new_group" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out and let me know if that works for you, I changed the inner layout from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and created what I believe you are looking for in relational locations.

**Note:** Be cautious of your `TextView` extending far enough to go behind the `ImageViews`, if that happens then it might be better to (set for the `ImageViews`):

```
android:layout_below="@+id/TvName"
```

on both and remove:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Right now I can not prove it, but I'm sure it will work when I try later.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you have any issues with it just let me know and I'll help as best I can. I did test it on my end and it appeared to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TvIdGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TV"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TVName"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImgNewConvGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImgNewGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TVDescription"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Take a look if is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is a lot of code just will write the structure

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
           <TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="right">
            <ImageView/>
            <ImageView/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you but my problem was in the parameters inside ImageView